# Dealing with multiple files with unique colnames

Tags: r

I was wondering what would be considered best practice for situations in which one has multiple csv files, with all of them having unique colnames. So file one might have tempKS or flame_KS, which file two might have tempCA or flame_CA. Basically, each file provides data on a different states, with the colnames in each file unique to that.

Let's say I want to build some linear models. Well, I could rewrite the 'same' code four times for each state, or I could try to standardize the colnames and run them individually on each file. My question is, what is considered best peace in situations where a user has multiple files and each has unique columns

Comment: use `grep` and `state.abb` to extract the state name, add it as a separate column then `rbind` all of the DTs

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
#dummy csv
write.csv(data.frame(tempKS=runif(10),flame_KS=runif(10)),
          file="temp1.csv",row.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE)
write.csv(data.frame(tempCA=runif(10),flame_CA=runif(10)),
          file="temp2.csv",row.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE)

#read csv, add batch, update colnames
output <- lapply(list.files(pattern="t*.csv"),
                 function(x){
                   tmp <- read.csv(x)
                   tmp$batch <- colnames(tmp)[1]
                   colnames(tmp)[1:2] <- c("temp","flame")
                   tmp})

#list to dataframe
do.call(rbind,output)
```